# Sort and Filter Pandas Dataframe in the most efficient manner

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter by the column name 'duration' and then display values greater than 200. This is just a snippet of the dataset. I have a very huge dataset. I can use df[df.duration > 200]. However, this runs on the entire dataframe. Is there any way in which I can specifically target the column duration and then filter the data and display only the column duration without introducing the new dataframe. Also some explanation related to optimization of the same in huge datasets(working environment) would be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390,100],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45,300]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: use boolean masking `df[df['duration'].gt(200)]`

Comment: You might to consider numpy

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas, I think `df[df.duration > 200]` would be among the best choices, but eager to compare with any alternatives.

Comment: This query will run on the entire dataset which will make it computationally expensive.
Any idea on how to filter a single column  and then apply the above query without using a new dataframe